# How to write multiple test functions in a single file in Matlab (TDD implementation)

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, tdd

I have different test cases to test the different functions. I want to write all the different functions in one .m file and one test file to check all the different test cases.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/write-simple-test-case-with-functions.html#zmw57dd0e66668

I followed the above link but I can see only one function implemented quadraticsolver but I want to implement multiple functions along with that for example calculating are of square, area of circle. can anyone help me in implementing multiple functions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More detailed about function-based tests can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/write-function-based-unit-tests-.html).

Briefly, to implement multiple tests within the same .m file, you'll need one main function that shares it's name with the file and this main function should  aggregate all local test functions within the file (using [`localfunctions`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/localfunctions.html)) and then create an array of tests from these functions using [`functiontests`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functiontests.html). Each local test function should accept one input (a [`matlab.unittest.TestCase`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.testcase-class.html) object).

**`my_tests.m`**

```
function tests = my_tests()
    tests = functiontests(localfunctions);
end

% One test
function test_one(testCase)
    testCase.assertTrue(true)
end

% Another test
function test_two(testCase)
    testCase.assertFalse(true);
end
```

Then in order to run these tests, you'll want to use [`runtests`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/runtests.html) and pass the filename or use `run` and pass the output of your function.

```
runtests('my_tests.m')
% or 
run(my_tests)
```

Based on the help section linked above, you can also create `setup` and `teardown` functions that will act as setup and teardown functions, respectively.

**Update**

Based upon your comments, if you now have your tests all within one file but you want all of your other functions (the ones you are testing) to also be in one file, you *can* do this but it's important to note that any local function defined within an .m file that isn't the main function will only be accessible to other functions *within that same file*. There is more information in [the documentation for local functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html).

Comment: how about implementing multiple functions from the above link if you take the example of quadraticSolver.m. There is a function to solve quadratic equation and I want to add another function to calculate area of a square. I want to implement different functions and pass the values fron the test file

Comment: @vinaykv What? I just showed you how to do it and showed you the correct link to determine how to do it. In my example `test_one` and `test_two` are two different test functions.

Comment: @vinaykv What part are you confused about still?

Comment: I got the adding test cases but I want to add more functions in quadraticSolver.m File in the above link like another function to calculate are of square as quadraticSolver generating the roots.

Comment: @vinaykv the `quadricSolver.m` file in the example they provide is just a normal `.m` file that you are going to test with a suite of tests. If you want to add more functions, create more `.m` files. If you make them subfunctions of that same file they will only be accessible to functions within that same file. See a more detailed discussion on that [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html)

Comment: Thank you I got the understanding now

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in grouping related functions into a single cohesive file, then you may want to look into making your function a class. Using a class you can create separate methods instead of multiple functions as you say. If you haven't written a lot of object oriented code, then this is the beginning of many great and wonderful (and also frightful and terrible) things you can do in your software.

For example you can do something like this (note this is in three separate *.m files):

```
% Shape.m
classdef Shape
    properties(Abstract)
        Area
        Circumference
    end
end

% Circle.m
classdef Circle < Shape
    properties(Dependent)
        Area
        Circumference
    end
    properties
        Radius
    end

    methods
        function circle = Circle(radius)
            circle.Radius = radius;
        end
        function area = get.Area(circle)
            area = pi*circle.Radius^2;
        end
        function circumference = get.Circumference(circle)
            circumference = 2*pi*circle.Radius;
        end
    end
end

% Rectangle.m
classdef Rectangle < Shape
    properties(Dependent)
        Area
        Circumference
    end
    properties
        Length
        Height
    end

    methods
        function rectangle = Rectangle(length, height)
            rectangle.Length = length;
            rectangle.Height = height;
        end
        function area = get.Area(rectangle)
            area = rectangle.Length*rectangle.Height;
        end
        function circumference = get.Circumference(rectangle)
            circumference = 2*(rectangle.Length+rectangle.Height);
        end
    end
end
```

Note I showed the use of multiple properties, but since they are dependent they actually act like functions. Each time you ask for the property the function get.*PropertyName* is called just like a function. Also, note I showed multiple functions (properties) in these classes, but I didn't just lump everything together in one. I put them together into two cohesive classes. This cohesion is important for software design and keeping the code maintainable.

That said, these shapes can then be interacted with as follows:

```
>> c = Circle(5);
>> c.Area % calls the get.Area "function"

ans =

   78.5398

>> c.Circumference

ans =

   31.4159

>> r = Rectangle(4,5);
>> r.Area

ans =

    20

>> r.Circumference

ans =

    18

>>
```

Get started [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html) and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/why-use-object-oriented-design.html).